# How to start a script properly from a starter terminal executed script in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, panel

Assume you have a starter in your panel which starts a script called foo.sh in terminal mode.

foo.sh than starts another script called bar.sh in background.

I run into problems:

First: the name of the written file from bar.sh differs.

Second and main: the bar.sh script is not independent and die when the terminal is closed.

I tested this on an old 16.04. machine.

foo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#read an user input
read -r -t 60 -p ":" foo
echo "$foo"

#call bar script
/home/$USER/bar.sh "10" "$foo" & disown

#show if bar.sh was started
echo $?

#sleep a short time to see the echo's
sleep 3
```

bar.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#sleep some time
[[ -n "$1" ]] && sleep $1

#then write user input to file called output
echo "$2 - sleept $1 seconds" >> /home/$USER/output
```

If the time to sleep in foo is greather than in bar the output file is written but called output? (with an ? at the end).

But if the time is larger in bar then bar is killed when foo finished and the terminal is closed.

Any idea how to set up correctly a background instance of bar.sh?

Another terminal which stays open is not a solution to me.

THX!

P.S. As a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027515/how-to-start-a-script-properly-from-a-starter-terminal-executed-script-in-ubuntu) suggested, I should ask my question here.

Comment: Usually to run anything even after session times out, you can use `nohup script_name.sh`. But I'm not sure this will also holds good while executing the script from another script. Let me know the result if you try with nohup.

Comment: Wunderful. It works! THX!!! the correct syntax is: **nohup /home/$USER/bar.sh "10" "$foo" > /dev/null &** If you like to write this as an answer I will accept it. If I write the output file with "" like "/home/$USER/output" the name is as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you told it worked, I'm giving this as an answer, with additional information.

"nohup" stands for "No Hungup". As the name suggests, it will continue to run the command without hanging up, even if session is disconnected. It is used to run commands on remote server which would take way long time to complete (backing up a DB etc).

Usually, the logs of script (if any) are stored in ~/nohup.out file. But you can choose to capture the logs, either by appending or replacing the logs of old contents with the new.
">" Single greater than sign will replace old logs with the new.
">>" double greater than sign will append the logs to the end of the file.

I'm using this below format to run the same thing in crontab. In this case, I'm replacing the old logs.
/path/to/script_folder/script_name.sh > /path/to/script_folder/logs/script_name.log 2>&1